# Несколько паттернов в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Необходимо по комментариям людей отсортировать строки 
Ищу с помощью регулярных выражений

```py
ax_part['MSK'][i] = 1. if re.search('МСК' or"MSK", ax_part['ax ТМ'][i]) else 0
```

Однако при работе этой строки отсортировываются только строки по паттерну `МСК`
Как изменить строку, чтобы искались все паттерны?

Comment: `'МСК|MSK'` или `'М[СS]K'`. `'МСК' or"MSK"` - это синтаксис Python для переменных, в регулярном выражении нужно использовать `|` внутри одной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Аргумент, содержащий регулярное выражение, должен быть строковым литералом. Чередования в регулярном выражении можно указывать с помощью оператора `|`:

```
if re.search(r'МСК|MSK', ax_part['ax ТМ'][i])
#                 ^
```

В данном случае можно упростить выражение до

```
if re.search(r'М[СS]K', ax_part['ax ТМ'][i])
```

Если есть какие-то шаблоны до и после, чередования следует группировать. Типичный пример с использованием границ слова (чтобы не находить `MCKA` или `AMSK`)

```
if re.search(r'\b(?:МСК|MSK)\b', ax_part['ax ТМ'][i])
#                ^^^   ^   ^
```

Вообще, в Pandas можно использовать [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['col'].str.contains(r'\b(?:МСК|MSK)\b').astype(int)
```

Тест:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'MSK': ['MSK 1', 'NOMSK 2', 'MCK 3', 'MCKA 4']})
df_test['MSK'].str.contains(r'\b(?:МСК|MSK)\b').astype(int)
# 0    1
# 1    0
# 2    0
# 3    0
# Name: MSK, dtype: int32
```